# Thunderbird Unified Inbox doesn't work for all accounts

Tags: macos, thunderbird, osx-el-capitan

I use Thunderbird as email client on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11). The Unified inbox doesn't work for two accounts. The sent folder is unified however.

Total 10 accounts

- 4 Gmail, all pop, of which 3 unified (inbox and sent)
- 5 provider accounts, all pop, 4 unified inboxes, 5 unified sent folders
- 1 provider account, imap, not unified (and that's OK)

**How can I get all accounts to appear in the unified inbox?**

Comment: More info needed here. How many accounts are present? Anything the two odd ones have in common (e.g. both from a specific provider, etc)? I see everything in unified inbox on my MBP (multiple Gmail accounts, Tb 38.4, OS X 10.11.2)

Comment: Are the two accounts in question using POP to sync with the server, or IMAP? I suspect this issue may be due to the limitations of POP: It works by deleting your email on the server as you download it, and therefore would be unsafe in some situations.

Comment: I updated the question. Two pop accounts have this problem, while others from the same providers work. The sent folder is unified for one account. If I compare the gmail account with a working gmail account, I don't see any differences in the Copies and Folders settings. The same for the provider accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been a while, but I had this issue today.

You must select the missing account folders for them to appear on the unified view. You can do that by following these instructions.

Right-click in the "Inbox" folder of the Unified Folders view. Click on "Properties". A dialogue will appear. Click on the "Choose folders..." button and another dialogue will appear. Scroll through the accounts checking each Inbox folder you wish it to appear on the unified view. Click on the "OK" button when done to close the dialogue, and then the "Update" button. Your missing inboxes will sync.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem again, completely forgot about this question, created another question about the same issue, then my own question came up and here you have the right answer!  

Answer (score 1):

Remove the accounts and add them again in Thunderbird.